# How to create Django click buttons in ajax template for Python callback functions

Tags: python, ajax, django, button, callback

I'm trying to create a template/ajax that three buttons that send three different parametervalues back to Python function according to the following;
- one variabel current_count starts with the value 0 and updates +-1 for each button click on one of the following clickbuttons;

Button1 - Click button 'Forward' returns the char 'F' from the template when clicked to the view function one_move() wherein it (the char 'F') is passed as a parameter to a Python -function that is executed when it receives a parameter.When clickbutton Forward is returned to the view it also increases the value of current_count with +1 current value(through an if statement)

Button2 - Click button 'Backward' returns the char 'D' from the template when clicked to the view function one_move() wherein it (the char 'D') is passed as a parameter to a Python -function that is executed when it receives a parameter.When clickbutton Backward is returned to the view it also decreases the value of current_count with -1 from it's current value(through an if statement)

Button3 - Click button 'OK' returns  chars 'S' from the template when clicked to the view function one_move() wherein it (the char 'S') is passed as a parameter to a Python -function that is executed when it receives a 
parameter.When clickbutton OK  the value of current_count remains unchanged, that is, with its current value.

The purpose of the above is to implement a pygame wherein the modelfields listview and sentence, which are passed through the Python callback function in one_move() in views.py, are displayed in the html as ["Dave", 8, "to", "work"] wherein 8 is a marker for current position and "went" is placed on the left of the list (which is done by the Python callback function). Pressing the clickbutton "Forward" results in the marker moving one step to the right per click, from "went" to "to", pressing "Backward" results in the marker moving one step to the left per click, e.g from "went" to "Dave", within the range of the list. The third button, OK, selects the word at the marker position, for instance "went". The listview is updated according to the current positionnumber in the variabel current_count.

in models.py

```
class MoveInList(models.Model):
    click_char = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    current_count = models.IntegerField()
    listview = models.TextField()
    sentence = models.TextField()

    # function to update increase/decrease in (self)current_count value

    def count_changes(self):
        count = self.change_set.filter(is_public=True).count()
        self.current_count = count
        self.save()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.current_count


class OneMove(models.Model):
     click_char = models.CharField(max_length=70)
     current_count = models.IntegerField()
     listview = models.TextField()
     sentence = models.TextField()
     belongsTo = models.ForeignKey(MoveInList)
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.click_count
```

in forms.py

```
class MoveInListForm(forms.Form):
    click_char  = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    current_count = forms.IntegerField()
    listview = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    sentence = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
```

in views.py

```
def MoveInListIndex(request):
    moves = MoveInList.objects.all()
    return render(request,"button.html", {"moves":moves})

def one_move(request,postID):
    one_moves = MoveInList.objects.get(id=postID)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MoveInListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            post_one_move(request, one_move)

        else:
            MoveInListForm()

    # PYTHON CALLBACK function is used with params from template
    c = {"one_move":one_move,"form":form}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request,"button.html", c)

def post_one_move(request, one_move):


    click_count = request.POST['click_count']
    current_count = request.POST['current_count']
    listview = request.POST['listview ']
    sentence = request.POST['sentence']



    clickMove = OneMove(belongsTo=one_move,click_count=click_count,current_count=current_count,listview=listview,sentence=sentence)
    clickMove.save()
```

in urls.py

```
url(r'^button$', MoveInListIndex),
url(r'^button/(?P<postID>\d+)$', one_move),
```

in template.py with ajax.py

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form  method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}

        Forward: <input type="submit" value="button""></input></br>
        Backward: <input type="submit" value="button""></input></br>
        OK: <input type="submit" value="button""></input></br>

         {{ form.as_p}}

    </form>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').on('click', function (e) {
            var current_count = $('#button').val();
            var data = { current_count :current_count  };
            var args = { dataType: "json", type:"POST", url:"/button/",
                        data:data, complete:ajax_call_complete };
            $.ajax(args);
        });
    });
    var ajax_call_complete = function(res, status) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(res.responseText);
        // use data as a json response object here and
        // do something with the response data
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment, the template button.html isn't returning or displaying anything and any advice on how to get the ajax going is highly appreciated.

Comment: if you debugging into `one_move`, is it really being invoked?

Comment: yes, the python callback is imported and works in one_move, the listview has shown up in the template in previous attempts but when I run it with "F" for Forward, "D" for Backward and so on on the keyboard the changed listviews only display in PyShell, although invoked by one_move (pardon, misspelled in the text above, should be one_move instead of one_view)

Comment: in sum, I need help with an ajax form that returns the values from the three buttons, namely the chars "F", "D" and "S" from the ajax template buttons.html so that they can be passed as parameters to the Python function in one_move(). In addition, the ajax would update/change current_count variabel value to keep track on indexposition based on which button is pressed .

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to use [HttpResponse()](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/HttpResponse) rather than `render()` to pass back the data to client side:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
import json

def one_move(request,postID):
    ...
    d = {"responseText": "your data here"}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(d))
```

Then you should be able to get the return in your `ajax_call_complete()` javascript function